# Metamask eth_signTypedData_v4 show Date and Price in a human readable format

Tags: javascript, ethereum, metamask

I'm using `eth_signTypedData_v4` method to sign an off-chain nft listing request.
My contract function requires price and date values in unit256.
when showing the message to the user Metamask displays these as raw numbers.

Is there a way to get these number to be displayed in a more readable format i.e. price values in ETH and date values in a more readable date format.

[image]

This is how I'm requesting the signature

````js
    const metamaskProvider = new Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    // Get the signer and account address
    const signer = metamaskProvider.getSigner();
    const marketPlaceContractName = "NFTMarketplace";
    const listingDomain = {
      name: marketPlaceContractName,
      version: "1",
      chainId: chainId, // or whatever chain ID you're using
      verifyingContract: marketPlaceAddress, // address of the contract
    };

    const listingTypes = {
      NftListing: [
        { name: "seller", type: "address" },
        { name: "nftAddress", type: "address" },
        { name: "nftId", type: "uint256" },
        { name: "startPrice", type: "uint256" },
        { name: "endPrice", type: "uint256" },
        { name: "startedAt", type: "uint256" },
        { name: "duration", type: "uint256" },
      ],
    };

    const listing = {
      seller: account,
      nftAddress: process.env.REACT_APP_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
      nftId: nftId,
      startPrice: BigNumber.from(parseEther("0.02")).toString(),
      endPrice: BigNumber.from(parseEther("0.01")).toString(),
      startedAt: timestampBefore,
      duration: 5 * 60,
    };

    const listSignature = await signer._signTypedData(
      listingDomain,
      listingTypes,
      listing
    );
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

MetaMask shows the human readable format because the `eth_signTypedData_v4` input is formatted according to the [EIP-712](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712) standard.

As per this standard, the data that you're signing **contains the field names and types** (e.g. if the value is a number or an address). Which effectively enables MetaMask and other wallets to display the fields.

---

When you're sending a transaction, the called function and its params are [ABI encoded](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html#argument-encoding).

ABI encoded payload only contains values - but **not the field names, nor their types**.

So if a wallet were to display the field names before sending a transaction, you'd need to pass them somehow to the wallet first. Currently there's no standardized way to do that, and that's possibly why wallet developers haven't introduced this option yet.

Edit: Specifically MetaMask [uses a 3rd party](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/registering-function-names.html) database of function selectors. So if your contract function is in this database, they will display the params even before sending a transaction.